# Please Help! -- GUI wallet Daemon failed to start and can't find log or monerod

Tags: monerod, monero-wallet-gui

I'm running the GUI wallet v0.15.0.2 with a Ledger Nano S (the Ledger is updated as of yesterday) on a mac. When I open the wallet I keep getting this message "Daemon failed to start. Please check your wallet and daemon log for errors. You can also try to start monerod manually."

I've scoured the monero guide and the internet and can't seem to solve this. I can't find monerod or monerod.exe on my computer and my firewall is completely turned off, so that's not the issue. I've re-downloaded the GUI app and still no monerod.exe.

How/where can I check the daemon log or run monerod manually? I'm really at a loss. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: connect to a monero remote node instead.

Comment: Are you trying to run your own full node on the same Mac as the GUI?  Or connect to someone else's node (much easier) as recommended by Patoshi?

Answer (score 0):

`monerod.exe` is not applicable, it is a Windows program.   You can find `monerod` inside the monero GUI app folder. It would be located here normally: `/Applications/monero-wallet-gui.app/Contents/MacOS/monerod`.  The GUI would be in the same folder.

It sounds like you are still very new to all of this, so you might consider [connecting to someone else's remote monero node](https://www.getmonero.org/resources/user-guides/remote_node_gui.html) initially, then setup your own full node once you have more experience.